# Prove if two normal extensions over a field are isomorphic

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, normal-extension

> Suppose $K_1,K_2$ are normal extensions over a field $F$ . Suppose the set of minimal polynomials of elements in $K_1$ over $F$ = the set of minimal polynomials of elements in $K_2$ over $F$ . Then are $K_1,K_2$ isomorphic ?

My attempt:

I have proved the fact that an algebraic extension $K |F$ is normal iff $\text{min}_F (\alpha)$ splits in $K[X] , \forall \alpha \in K$ . Combining this with the hypothesis that the set of minimal polynomials of elements in $K_1$ over $F$ = the set of minimal polynomials of elements in $K_2$ over $F$, it seems to me that in fact $K_1$ must equal $K_2 $, but I do not have proof.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: If $a\in K_1$, then the minimal polynomail of $a$ is the minimal polynomial of some element of $K_2$; thus, the minimal polynomial of $a$ must split in $K_2$ (because it has at least one root in $K_2$), and so $a\in K_2$.

Comment: Yeah! So in particular $K_1 = K_2$ ? Right?

Comment: (Note that you could in principle have $K_1$ and $K_2$ contained in “different” algebraic closures, so they need not be equal; but you can always map $K_1$ into, say, the algebraic closure of $K_2$ over $F$ so that you may assume that $K_1$ and $K_2$ are in fact contained in a common overfield of $F$, so that you would get equality rather than isomorphism).

Comment: In case, $K_1$ and $K_2$ are contained in two different Algebraic closures, can you please provide more details regarding isomorphism (without considering 'you may assume that $K_1$ and $K_2$ are in fact contained in a common overfield of F$ ) ?

Comment: One of the properties of normal extensions is that if $K_1$ is a normal extension of $F$, and $L$ is an algebraic closure of $F$, then there is an embedding of $K_1$ into $L$ over $F$. So you can always map $K_1$ into the algebraic closure of $K_2$ without “disturbing” $F$, and work with that isomorphic copy of $K_1$. That’s why the question asks about isomorphism rather than equality.